# How do I create a TCP listener with netcat and put it in the background?

Tags: netcat

I’m using `nc -l` to create a listener socket, but then it just.....listens.....and I can’t issue any further commands.

How do I put it in the background so I can maintain the listener and keep issuing commands in the CLI? I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put and ampersand (&) at the end of the command.

```
$ nc -l 8080 &
```

It might be better to open another terminal window though, and keep your listener in the foreground.